# Time machine removed usr/bin/sudo. How can I get it back?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I had some issues with my Macbook, and I used Time Machine to recover a version of `usr/bin`. Unfortunately, somewhere along the process, `usr/bin/sudo` was removed.

Now, even if I want to recover usr/bin/sudo from a past backup, I won't have permission to write to `user/bin`.

How can I fix problem? I already spent a day trying to fix it.

Update:

I only have issue with usr/bin/sudo. I even have recovered version of it in another directory. I just can't write to usr/bin because I don't have right to write. So I hope I can restart my Mac in some special mode to be able to write to this directory.

Comment: Any information you can give regarding what was changed using Time Machine would be helpful. For example, was /usr/bin/sudo moved or renamed at some point or was it just deleted?

Comment: @JoelTaylor: does it matter? the sudo-binary is disfunctional, OP wants it back.

Comment: If adamYNC, at some point, followed a process similar to http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1625829 /usr/bin/sudo could be somewhere else and it would just be a matter of executing the renamed binary.

Comment: If you don't have `sudo` you might still be able to start a new shell as root, like `su bash`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg That won't work unfortunately.. you'd have to use `sudo su`. Using `su` alone is not possible as there's no root account.

Comment: @slhck `su` without arguments does work if you have enabled the root user from Directory Utility or with `dsenableroot`.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the system. Sure, it's time-consuming, but it would take less time than you've already spent.

**If** it's not a  MacBook Air and **If** you have another Mac (which is also not a Macbook Air) and a Firewire cable to link them, you could start it up in target disk mode and work on it from another machine. If you don't have those things, see above - The advice was offered based on a good deal of pragmatic practical experience...you can easily spend more time getting all that together than you'd spend reinstalling.

Comment: I've voted this up because it's a good enough answer, but it also reminds me that one can boot off a DVD or recovery partition, which may contain a valid version of `sudo` that can be copied over.

Comment: Given that /usr/bin was already corrupted or had things deleted enough to need recovery, and then _that_ went "mysteriously wrong" and ate sudo, wholesale is not a bad option, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use Finder to copy the `sudo` binary from a backup? It should keep the owner as `root`, and authenticating as a superuser in Finder does not require `/usr/bin/sudo` to exist.

If others who get here from seach engines don't have a `sudo` binary, you can download an OS X installer application from App Store and use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) to extract the binary. [Doing an upgrade install of OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763) or upgrading to a new major version of OS X also restores files like `/usr/bin/sudo`.